# Parse xml to multiple Classes

Tags: xml, vb.net, class, parsing

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Resp>
  <dData>
    <Desc></Desc>
    <dId></dId>
    <Num></Num>
    <Ref></Ref>
    <Ms></Ms>
    <Im></Im>
  </dData>
  <Type></Type>
  <RespData>
    <dc></dc>
    <sString></sString>
  </RespData>
</Resp>
```

And the following classes:

```
Public Class dData
    Public Property Desc As String       
    Public Property DID As String   
    Public Property Num As Integer       
    Public Property Ref As String     
    Public Property Ms As String        
    Public Property Im As String        
End Class

Public Class RespData
    Public Property DC As Integer           
    Public Property sString As String
End Class
```

And finally a combination of the above:

```
Public Class Resp
    Public Property URData As dData
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property URRespData As RespData
End Class
```

I want to parse the XML above into the class Resp.

I saved the XML file into an `XMLDocument` called `XmlInput` and I wrote this:

```
Dim handleXML = From h In xmlInput.Elements("Resp")
```

Then `handleXML.Count` returned `1`

I expected `HandleXML.Count` to return `3` (dData,Type,RespData)

and then I loop in each element's nodes and save values into the class that it belongs to. 
But it returned `1`.

Am I doing anything wrong?
Is there a better method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should implement the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and then use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class to serialize/deserialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expected HandleXML.Count to return 3 (dData,Type,RespData)

No. 1 is the correct output because your XML contains only one `<Resp>` element. To get chldren of the `<Resp>` you should've gone one more level down the tree :

```
Dim handleXML = From h In xmlInput.Elements("Resp").Elements()
'here handleXML.Count is 3'
```

You may also want to consider a different route, look into XML serialization/deserialization : [MSDN: `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).